# Как использовать натренированную модели нейронной сети на основе Keras, подавая на вход одно изображение?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

В общем, есть нейронная сеть, написанная и натренированная, используя библиотеку Keras. Предположим, это классическое распознавание рукописных цифр, используя MNIST датасет. Веса нейронной сети и архитектуру можно сохранить для переиспользования стандартными функциями библиотеки. Возник вопрос, который все документации и туториалы обходят стороной почему-то. Как подать на вход нейр. сети ОДНУ фотку, например, jpg с цифрой 3 и получить предсказание нейронной сети, что это скорей всего цифра три?

Comment: А как вы подаете не одну, а много?

Answer (score 1):

в примерах мы видим следующее:

```
out = model.predict(x) 
print(np.argmax(out))
```

если в **x** будет только один элемент, то и предсказание будет для единственного значения. вот и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
orig_images = [] 
input_images = [] 

img_path = 'examples/fish_bike.jpg'

orig_images.append(imread(img_path))
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
img = image.img_to_array(img) 
input_images.append(img)
input_images = np.array(input_images)
```